# How to get a list of nested links for a Revit model using Forge APIs

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I can acquire the full list of nested links in a Revit model using Revit APIs by this query:

```
  FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(document);
  return collector.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_RvtLinks)
    .OfClass(typeof(RevitLinkInstance))
    .Cast<RevitLinkInstance>()
    .Select(linkInstance => document.GetElement(linkInstance.GetTypeId()) as RevitLinkType)
    .Where(revitLinkType => revitLinkType.IsNestedLink)
    .Select(type => type.Name)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

I am trying to replicate the same function using Forge APIs. While I can't get the nested links directly, I am hoping to get it in two steps.

First: acquire the list of linked docs,
Second: query the linked docs on every linked document acquired in step one.

I am using this API to get the list of linked docs for step one:

'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/[project_id]/versions/[version_id]/relationships/refs'

That returns a list that includes: linked docs, the document itself, and any document that has the document linked in. So for example:

If A links B,
and B links C,
When I call the API on B, I get A, B and C. Now, it's easy to eliminate B from the response, but it's a bit confusing to figure out between A and C which one is a linked document.

I checked all the attributes and couldn't find anything, is there something I am missing? Also, is this the best way to acquire the list of nested linked documents?

Answer (score 0):

To identify which file is the host or link, we can take a look at the `direction` attribute of the responses of [GET    projects/:project_id/versions/:version_id/relationships/refs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-relationships-refs-GET/)

Here are two example responses representing the host and link correspondingly.

```json
//Host Model
"data": [
    {
        "type": "versions",
        "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.n4QEQGINSWid8VvcBVds1w?version=1",
        "meta": {
            "refType": "xrefs",
            "fromId": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.n4QEQGINSWid8VvcBVds1w?version=1",
            "fromType": "versions",
            "toId": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.y6GJ2scBSVSyIRM_wtEsDA?version=1",
            "toType": "versions",
            "direction": "to",
            "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "schema": {
                    "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref-1.1"
                },
                "data": {
                    "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
            }
        }
    }
],
```

```json
// Link model
"data": [
    {
        "type": "versions",
        "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.y6GJ2scBSVSyIRM_wtEsDA?version=1",
        "meta": {
            "refType": "xrefs",
            "fromId": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.n4QEQGINSWid8VvcBVds1w?version=1",
            "fromType": "versions",
            "toId": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.y6GJ2scBSVSyIRM_wtEsDA?version=1",
            "toType": "versions",
            "direction": "from",
            "extension": {
                "type": "xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref",
                "version": "1.1",
                "schema": {
                    "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/xrefs:autodesk.core:Xref-1.1"
                },
                "data": {
                    "nestedType": "overlay"
                }
            }
        }
    }
],
```

The `direction` attribute has two possible values, one is `to` and another is `from`.

In the above example, host `urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.n4QEQGINSWid8VvcBVds1w?version=1` is linked to `urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.y6GJ2scBSVSyIRM_wtEsDA?version=1`. Consider it like an arrow with the head pointing `to`-wards the link model.

What you see from link model perspective is simply the reverse, the arrow is coming from the host `urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.n4QEQGINSWid8VvcBVds1w?version=1`.

In both example responses, the `fromId` and `toId` don't change, only the `direction` of the `arrow` depending from which perspective you're looking at.

Comment: Hi Eason, thank you for your response. When I look at the documentation for POST projects/:project_id/versions/:version_id/relationships/refs, it looks like it's to create a link between two models:

Comment: Thanks for the response Eason. Ok so if I use the 'GET' equivalent it works as you described. However, I can only get it to work on smaller test models, the API simply returns an empty array for data, even though the project does have several linked document (see the answer that I posted for more details)

Comment: Sounds like it's a Revit Cloud Worksharing model that has unpublished links. Could you help check if its version attribute has this value: `extension.type: versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel`?

Comment: Hi Eason, where can I check extension.type: versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel. Which API can I use for that?

Comment: Hi Eason, The links are published. Which API should I use to check extension.type: versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel?  Also, should I check that on the main model or on the links?

Comment: Either of [GET version/:id](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-version_id-GET/), [GET versions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-versions-GET/) or [GET Folder Contents](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/) can see item versions. If the model is c4r model, it sohuld have the extension type I mentioned above.

Comment: Hi Eason, I checked the extension type, and it's "items:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel"

Comment: Hi Ehsan, it's almost like either of your linked RVTs is not published to Cloud Model while the host model was published. Could you help check if this model behaves like 
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/bim-360/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Why-a-RVT-model-is-sometimes-downloaded-as-ZIP-from-BIM-360.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response Eason. Ok so if I use the 'GET' equivalent it works as you described. However, I can only get it to work on smaller test models, the API simply returns an empty array for data, even though the project does have several linked document:

```
{
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.19e2199f-4132-4c47-9972-37d4708ea59f/versions/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.ZhP9FgAOTx6T4EV8acbrJg%3Fversion=27/relationships/refs"
    },
    "related": {
      "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.19e2199f-4132-4c47-9972-37d4708ea59f/versions/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.ZhP9FgAOTx6T4EV8acbrJg%3Fversion=27/refs"
    }
  },
  "data": []
}
```

Are there any limits for this API? Why would this work on some models and not on the other ones?

Comment: See my comments below. It looks like a Revit Cloud Worksharing model that has unpublished links. Could you help check if its version attribute has this value: extension.type: versions:autodesk.bim360:C4RModel?